# Ensure children finish before parent ends

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
```

(not pthread or semaphore)

If the above are the only libraries I use, how do I ensure that the readers wait for the first writer input before loading from the shared buffer?

When I run the program, the reader prints the junk value in the buffer before I have the writer to call user input. And `scanf` does not work, it does not wait for any user input and it keeps going.
It looks like the main process ends before all the children finish, and if that happens, children stop taking input, so is there a way to solve?

like:

```
@ubuntu.....(returned?)
reader gets the data:1
Enter your data:
reader gets the data:1
```

My source code is below:

```
void reader(int i) 
{
   int data;
   if(nextp == N)
      nextp=0;
   printf("\nEnter the data(writer %d) :",i);
   scanf("%d",(buffer+nextp));
   nextp++;
}

void writer(int i)
{
   int g;
   if(nextc == N)
      nextc=0;
   g=*(buffer+nextc++);
   printf("\nreader %d gets the data:%d\n",i,g);
}

in main():
int k;
for(k=RW;k>0;--k)//RW is number of readers and writers
{
   pid = fork();
   if(!pid)
   {
      pid = fork();
      if(pid>0)//writer (child)
      {
         for(i=0;i<N;i++)
         {
            P(empty); 
            P(mutex); // Entering critical section
            P(write);
            writer(k);
            V(write);
            V(mutex); // Exit from critical section
            V(full); 
         }
         wait();
      }

      if(pid==0)//reader (grandchild)
      {

         int readsize;
         readsize = N*RW;
         for(i=0;i<readsize;i++)
         {
            P(full);
            P(mutex); // Entering critical section
            P(rd_count);
            if(N-1 == (j=sem_val(rd_count))) /* Write lock for first reader */
               P(write); /* Once we have it, it keeps writers at bay */
            V(mutex); 
            reader(k);
            P(mutex);
            V(rd_count);
            if(N == (j=sem_val(rd_count))) /* When last reader leaves: */
               V(write);                   /* Allow writers */
            V(mutex);
            V(empty); // Exit from critical section
         }
         wait();
      }
   }
}
```

`sem_val` is custom `getval` function.

`P` is custom -1 semop function.

`V` is custom +1 semop function.

If there are logic or syntax error, please feel free to point it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem you faced?

Comment: It looks fine to me. If any problem is faced, mention it.

Comment: When I run the program, the reader prints the junk value in the buffer before I have the writer to call user input.

Comment: Would I be a problem if I call scanf multiple times and it accidentally traps in \n so that it cannot get any input?

Answer (score -1):

Because, memory resource is not shared when a process is created by `fork`. Rather try `vfork`.

Each child process has its own memory when created by `fork`.

Please make sure that semaphores being used should synchronize the process too.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. vfork is useful in reducing memory size, but I still cannot stop the reader to print junk. Should I clear the buffer?

Comment: First ensure that same memory is being used.

Comment: shmid=shmget(1000,BUFSIZE,IPC_CREAT | 0666)
For this situation, if 1000 remains the same, is the memory the same?

Comment: Yes. It should be same.

Comment: Somehow the writer does not take the last output when I have more than one writer-reader pair. The reader in the last loop (get its last input)behaves like the output above.

Comment: vfork does not work for this situation, and in general ought not be used in linux.